# How to enforce Hard Constraint that certain nodes should not be visited first and last in VRP of Google OR tools

Tags: java, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to enforce a constraint that certain nodes should not be visited at the starting of the trip or when the trip ends in a VRP problem. Is there a way to enforce such constraint in Google OR tools? 
FYI Language I am using is java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify the range of the nextVar variable.

E.g. To forbid the arc `start` -> `index` for each vehicles.

Java:

```java
long toIndex = manager.nodeToIndex(index); 
for(int i = 0; i < vehicleNumber; ++i) {
  long fromIndex = routing.start(i);
  logger.info("Forbidding connection " + fromIndex + " -> " + toIndex);
  routing.nextVar(fromIndex).removeValue(toIndex);
}
```

.Net

```cs
long toIndex = manager.NodeToIndex(index); 
for (int i = 0; i < vehicleNumber; ++i) {
  long fromIndex = routing.Start(i);
  Console.WriteLine($"Forbidding connection {fromIndex} -> {toIndex}");
  routing.NextVar(fromIndex).RemoveValue(toIndex);
}
```

Python

```py
to_index = manager.NodeToIndex(index);
for i in range(vehicle_number):
  from_index = routing.Start(i)
  print(f"Forbidding connection {from_index} -> {to_index}")
  routing.NextVar(from_index).RemoveValue(to_index)
```

And basically the same for `index` -> `end` node.

Java:

```java
long fromIndex = manager.nodeToIndex(index); 
for(int i = 0; i < vehicleNumber; ++i) {
  long toIndex = routing.end(i);
  logger.info("Forbidding connection " + fromIndex + " -> " + toIndex);
  routing.nextVar(fromIndex).removeValue(toIndex);
}
```

.Net

```cs
long fromIndex = manager.NodeToIndex(index); 
for (int i = 0; i < vehicleNumber; ++i) {
  long toIndex = routing.End(i);
  Console.WriteLine($"Forbidding connection {fromIndex} -> {toIndex}");
  routing.NextVar(fromIndex).RemoveValue(toIndex);
}
```

Python

```py
from_index = manager.NodeToIndex(index);
for i in range(vehicle_number):
  to_index = routing.End(i)
  print(f"Forbidding connection {from_index} -> {to_index}")
  routing.NextVar(from_index).RemoveValue(to_index)
```

Comment: Are there any tutorials or reference material to learn OR tools except of the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to tweak the distance matrix such that the only incoming arcs of the 'firsts' are from the depot, and the only outgoing arcs from the lasts are to the depot.